# Joomla user real name as username

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm trying to edit joomla homepage. The homepage has a latest articles module by mod_articles_category. Everythings works fine but in article showing written by: Super User.

I want to show not real name but username. I'm trying:

```
<?php echo $item->author; ?>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This addition should give you the author username.

```
echo JFactory::getUser($this->item->created_by)->username;
```